# physical significance of triple integral of scalar field with respect to dx dy dz

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The volume of a surface V is given by:

$\text{volume of V} = \iiint \limits_{V}1 ~dx~dy~dz$

Intuitively, What's the physical meaning of the equation, if you modify the equation for volume by replacing 1 by a scalar field f(x,y,z)?

$?\text{weighted volume of V}¿ = \iiint \limits_{V}f(x,y,z) ~dx~dy~dz$

Is this the volume weighted by a scalar field f(x,y,z), or does it have some other meaning?

like "volume over scalar field?".

Comment: Sure.  You can also think of it $f(x,y,z)$ as density at which point the result will be the mass of your object.

Comment: thanks.  that's helpful.